# Mass update on table. Error 'Msg 512 - Subquery returned more than 1 value. ...'

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

I am trying to execute a mass update on table based on a condition.

```
UPDATE  POHeader
SET     POStatus = 'Cancelled'
WHERE   POStatus = 'Draft'
    AND Created <= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, '', GETDATE())-29, '')
```

I even tried these which also return the same error:

```
UPDATE  POHeader
SET     POStatus = 'Cancelled'
WHERE   POID in (18364, 26401, 27284, 28575, 30532, 30599, 33650,
                 33780, 33783, 33785, 33895, 35644, 35647, 35678,
                 37400, 37546, 38750, 38758, 40568, 42045, ......)
```

Please help as the amount to update is reaching thousands and doing it 1 by 1 is not an option.

## UPDATE Trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[POHeader_UPDATE]
   ON  [dbo].[POHeader]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[POHeaderLog]
           ([ActionDate]
           ,[Action]
           ,[POID]
           ,[CustomerName]
           ,[CustomerCode]
           , ...)
VALUES
           (GETDATE()
           ,'Update'
           ,(select INSERTED.POID from INSERTED)
           ,(select INSERTED.CustomerName from INSERTED)
           ,(select INSERTED.CustomerCode from INSERTED)
           , ...)

END
```

Comment: This query cannot possibly raise that error. Please show us your actual query...

Comment: There is no subquery in that SQL, so it cannot generate that error.

Comment: Edited the query with an actual ones ( I only modified the table names thats it). I'm afraid but that is the error I get when I executed the query. I too was surprised !

Comment: By the way, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18333.0

Comment: @Helmi-Fikri: is there some trigger on that table?

Comment: @GMB Checked with SELECT * FROM SYS.TRIGGERS. Yes there are 2. Trigger on CREATE & UPDATE. Is this the cause?

Comment: @Helmi-Fikri: yes, most likely the `UPDATE` trigger is not well-formed, and raises the error that you are getting. You would need to review the code of that trigger, and fix it.

Comment: @GMB A bit reading done on triggers. Thanks pointing that out.

Comment: @GMB Have checked the trigger. I've included the trigger in the question. In my view its well formed and should not stop the mass update. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the trigger code. SQL Server's trigger operate a *statement* level, so there will be multiple rows in `inserted`. if the `update` statement that fired the trigger affected more than one row - hence the error that you are getting.

You can rewrite the trigger code using the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[POHeader_UPDATE]
   ON  [dbo].[POHeader]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[POHeaderLog]
               ([ActionDate]
               ,[Action]
               ,[POID]
               ,[CustomerName]
               ,[CustomerCode]
               , ...)
    SELECT
               GETDATE()
               ,'Update'
               ,POID
               ,CustomerName
               CustomerCode,
               , ...
    FROM inserted;
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise. It solved my mass update issue.